# 文章の形態素解析による類似度の値について

Tags: r

http://tkdmah.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/02/23/002435
のサイトにおいて図の類似度行列の数値を出すのは、スコア付のセンチメント分析ですか？
また、①・②の行列類似度ではどのような結果を 
出せるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

[SimDoc: Topic Sequence Alignment based Document Similarity Framework](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.04822.pdf)
が　SimDocについての論文だと思います。

一行で言えるほど単純ではなさそうです。